# Converting back and forth between ISO week calendar date and a Joda Time types

Tags: jodatime

ISO 8601 defines an [ISO week date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). It can be used to represent a date like so:

- `2013-10-05` equals `2013-W40-6`, which is a date in ISO week `2013-W40`
- `2008-12-29` equals `2009-W01-1`, which is a date in ISO week `2009-W01`.

How can I convert back and forth between ISO week dates and Joda Time types such as `ReadableDateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

Use Joda Time's provided `ISODateTimeFormat`.
It has the following methods:

- `ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeekDay()` and `ISODateTimeFormat.weekDate()` (for formats such as `2009-W01-1`)
- `ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeek()` (for formats such as `2009-W01`)
- `ISODateTimeFormat.basicWeekDate()` (for compact formats such as `2009W011`)

They can be used like this:

```
ReadableDateTime endOfYearDateTime = DateTime.parse("2008-12-29T13:06Z");
logger.info("endOfYearDateTime        : {}", endOfYearDateTime);

String endOfYearISOWeekDateString = ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeekDay().print(endOfYearDateTime);
logger.info("isoCalendarWeekDateString: {}", endOfYearISOWeekDateString);

ReadableDateTime reverseEndOfYearDateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeekDay().parseDateTime(endOfYearISOWeekDateString);
logger.info("reverseEndOfYearDateTime : {}", reverseEndOfYearDateTime);
```

---

The above code will log the following data:

```
endOfYearDateTime        : 2008-12-29T13:06:00.000Z
isoCalendarWeekDateString: 2009-W01-1
reverseEndOfYearDateTime : 2008-12-29T00:00:00.000+01:00
```